# Push/Fetch with AWS CodeCommit in Visual Studio 403 Error

Tags: git, visual-studio, aws-codecommit

I already have a git repo on which I do my work locally. I tried to push this local repo to AWS CodeCommit in order to find out if my co-worker and me can use it as a collaboration tool. I set up the AWS Explorer for Visual Studio and I also added my user which I only use for programmatic access to AWS to Visual Studio. I also got a set of git credentials for that user.

So far I keep running into various problems. I'm unable to fetch or push, every time I try I get a non-specific error á la

```
Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/TestRepo/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Pushing to https://git-codecommit.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/TestRepo
```

Other things that don't work are I cannot create a new repo that shows up in Visual Studio. It can only be seen in the AWS Console

How can I now use an existed Repo on AWS to push my commits to?

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issue and need to remove git credential helper and move towards git credentials.

If you use static credentials, it will keep things simple.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/introducing-git-credentials-a-simple-way-to-connect-to-aws-codecommit-repositories-using-a-static-user-name-and-password/

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can now push my Commits to AWS using the CLI, but I still cannot push them within the Team Explorer in Visual Studio. That gives me the same error message

Answer (score 0):

> Other things that don't work are I cannot create a new repo that shows up in Visual Studio. It can only be seen in the AWS Console

This part sounds like there may be one of a few potential issues.

1. Visual Studio is likely accessing AWS using the user 'for programatic access' you mentioned. You should make sure that the IAM permission policies for that user include CodeCommit permissions. The easiest thing would be to attach the AWSCodeCommitFullAccess managed policy to your user if it is not there already. Also, be sure to check there are no policies attached to your user which Deny CodeCommit actions (or KMS actions).
2. Make sure Visual Studio is configured for the correct region. AWS CodeCommit repositories are regional, meaning that if you create a repository in Virginia, for example, that repository won't exist if you attempt to access it from the Dublin endpoint, for example. If VS is configured for a different region than the repository is in, it could explain why it isn't showing up.

Further reading: Visual Studio setup guide in CodeCommit docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ide-vs.html